# ¿Cual es la función del tag <a name="_gjdgxs"></a>? ¿Cual es su origen?

Tags: xml, xhtml, docx, wysiwyg

En la empresa tenemos un editor de texto wysiwyg para el uso interno de los empleados el cual fue modificado para realizar resaltado y comentarios utilizando etiquetas

Por ejemplo `<a id="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" name="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx">Jon Gomez</a>`

Ellos generan textos que luego serán presentados a otro departamento.

Al momento de presentar estos texto a otro departamento los mismos no deben poseer resaltado ni comentarios, por lo que el resaltado de los texto se borra mediante una expresión regular.

Si bien puedo borrar esta etiqueta, me interesa saber ¿cual es su origen? ya que realizamos pruebas copiando textos desde word y no logramos que aparezca la etiqueta **`<a name="_gjdgxs"></a>`** en cuestión pero si a aparecido en textos de usuarios y no sabemos el motivo.

Comment: Pareciera generado por el editor WYSIWYG cuando dejan anchors sin datos